# Probability calculation of the measurement of the total angular momentum for an electron

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, electrons, probability

Hello fellow physicists,
I will start with an example:
An electron has an orbital angular momentum of **l=2** and **ml=2**. Say its spin is **ms=-1/2** . What is the probability of the measurement of the total angular momentum to equal **j=3/2**

I know that the total angular momentum can have values that range from **j**min **=|l-s|** to **j**max = **l+s** but I don't get how the probability calculation works math-wise. I am also aware that I have to construct the probability using J_ and J+ operators but my bibliography is of poor quality.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial state can be writen as $\vert 2,2\rangle\vert 1/2,-1/2\rangle$.  The probability of finding it in the $j=3/2, m_j=3/2$ state is just
$$
\vert \langle 3/2,3/2\vert 2,2;1/2,-1/2\rangle\vert^2=
\vert C_{2,2;1/2,-1/2}^{3/2,3/2}\vert^2
$$
where 
$$
C_{2,2;1/2,-1/2}^{3/2,3/2}=\langle 3/2,3/2\vert 2,2;1/2,-1/2\rangle
$$
is a Clebsch-Gordan coefficient.  This CG is $2/\sqrt{5}$ so your probability is $4/5$.

Comment: You just showed me an invaluable tool for the quick computation of these probabilities. I was looking for the actual process of constructing the **3/2, 3/2** ket but thank you for answering.